# YouTube login with Gmail account

Tags: youtube, openid

YouTube allows to login via Google account. However, you need to have a YouTube account.

When I clicked **sign in with Google account**, it showed me two options:

1. Associate your YouTube account with Google account.
2. Sign out of Google account and create a new one.

Is there any way I can have single sign-on without creating a separate YouTube account?

(Just like SO's OpenID login where they create an account on the fly).

Comment: Gmail account integration with YouTube is very confusing (to me atleast)

Answer (score 3):

That is what option one ("Associate your YouTube account with Google account") allows you to do. YouTube only asks for a few extra pieces of information that may not be provided from your Google account.

Comment: Also because YouTube wasn't part of Google in the beginning and somebody could have already an account on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

See also this description:
"How to use my Blogspot OpenID as YouTube user name?"
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=38d2b92785aff93d&hl=en